# MSI write the TARGETDIR to textfile

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installscript-msi

How to write MSI's `TARGETDIR` to a textfile? So that my program can refer to the path written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the type of text file. If it is a plain text file you would have to use a custom action. Alternatively you can use the Windows Installer built in INI file editing support.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369282(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369282%28VS.85%29.aspx)